# MySQL: Joining two tables / Read all data from specific row in table B if specific field in table A is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRH9c.jpg (Please see Example Image of Database Structure)

Hi all,

I'm trying to search for words in two tables that Start with a specific Letter and I don't know how to do the proper join.

**If there is NOT given a voc_id in "user_vocabulary" I want to take the word from user_vocabulary but if there is a voc_id I want to read all data from "system_vocabulary" WHERE user_vocabulary.voc_id=system.vocabulary.id .**

This I use to just read one table (just for your information):
    SELECT * FROM user_vocabulary WHERE word LIKE '$user_input%' ORDER BY word ASC

I've found some more or less similar posts but seem not to be able to convert those to this issue.

Any help is much appreciated.
cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want values taken from `user_vocabulary.word` and `system_vocabulary.word` to end up in the same column in the output.  You can do this with the `IF` function:

```
SELECT
  uv.id,
  IF(uv.voc_id = 0,uv.word,sv.word) AS WORD
FROM user_vocabulary uv
LEFT JOIN system_vocabulary sv
ON (uv.voc_id = sv.id)
HAVING word LIKE '%user_input%'

+------+-------+
| id   | word  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | hat   |
|    2 | home  |
|    3 | hello |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In this reduced example it worked like a charm. 
<br/>
Only if I want to add another restriction to the query I'm getting (Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource):
<br/>
I wanted to add: WHERE uv.isOnline='1' so I tried this:
`
SELECT
  uv.id,
  IF(uv.voc_id = 0,uv.word,sv.word) AS WORD
FROM user_vocabulary uv **WHERE uv.online='1'**
LEFT JOIN system_vocabulary sv
ON (uv.voc_id = sv.id)
HAVING word LIKE '%user_input%'
`

Comment: For that example, I think you can just move the `WHERE` clause to the end, like this: `SELECT uv.id, IF(uv.voc_id = 0,uv.word,sv.word) AS word FROM user_vocabulary uv LEFT JOIN system_vocabulary sv ON (uv.voc_id = sv.id) WHERE uv.is_online = 1  HAVING word like "ho%";`

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but just so others know I think it was rather a spelling mistake of me, I think either position of the WHERE clause will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM user_vocabulary
left join system_vocabulary
on system_vocabulary.voc_id = user_vocabulary.id
WHERE user_vocabulary.word LIKE '%$user_input%' or system_vocabulary.word like     '%$user_input%'
ORDER BY word ASC
```

EDITED

The other way

```
SELECT *
FROM user_vocabulary as uv
, system_vocabulary as sv
WHERE uv.word LIKE '%$user_input%'
or sv.word like '%$user_input%'
```

Comment: Another thing is that if there is no word in the first table it will search in the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a go. First query looks complete, in the second I have to add the lines with the ids (on system_vocabulary.voc_id = user_vocabulary.id) right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work according to your requirements:

```
SELECT user_vocabulary.id,
   COALESCE(system_vocabulary.word, user_vocabulary.word) word
FROM user_vocabulary
LEFT JOIN system_vocabulary
   ON system_vocabulary.id = voc_id AND voc_id <> 0
```